# gitignore file but not folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a folder named the format

```
*.*.*.*.log
```

I also want to ignore *.log files
but the entry

```
*.log
```

In gitignore is ignoring my whole folder.

How do I ignore *.log files but not *.log directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found that

```
/*.log
```

will do the trick.